# Standalone doctrine annotation routing - cannot load resource

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations

I have a `routes.yml` file

```
controllers:
    resource: ../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

I am trying to load it

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader([$loader, 'loadClass']);

$locator = new FileLocator([__DIR__.'/../config']);
$loader = new YamlFileLoader($locator);

$routeCollection  = new RouteCollection();
$importedRoutes = $loader->load("routes.yml");
```

And I get

> Cannot load resource "../src/Controller/". Make sure annotations are installed and enabled.

I have tried variations, with and without quotes, backslashes, forward slashes...

```
"../src/Controller/"
"../src/Controller/API.php"
```

I have both `doctrine/annotations` and `sensio/framework-extra-bundle` installed

A similar issue came up in the [Symfony Github issues](https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/23#issuecomment-291740698), but I seem to have done what the solution is, according to Fabien Potencier.

To clarify, I am not using the complete Symfony package, but trying to use individual components to build the routing. Any ideas why I am getting this error message?

Comment: You are using symfony flex? It does not seems to be loaded manually [in this doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html)

Comment: @goto no I am not using flex, but I google'd the error message and that was one of the only results I found

Comment: Can you copy/paste your config file ? Do you have enable `annotations` for router ? According to the documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/index.html#configuration

Comment: @RomainNorberg you've sent me down the rabbit hole so I will update the question when I am stuck again.

Comment: it's ok for u ?

Comment: @RomainNorberg I can get annotations working. It requires me to set up an AppKernel, register bundles (just the symfony framework not sensio or annotations - I didn't need to set the config like your link). However, I am still getting some error with the entity and namespace, but I can create a new ticket for that.